# Creating and animating a SVG element (using D3.js?) on top of a Leaflet.js map at specific coordinates?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet

My task is to animate a series of circles on specific coordinates on top of a map created using Leaflet.js. I obtain the coordinates to place the circles at using websockets.

I am able to receive the events(coordinates) from a websocket connection and within the event handler I would like to add the code to add the circle to that coordinate.

The issue is that I am unable to find any resource which can help me accomplish what I need to do. There are approaches where they have used overlay panes, there is an approach where they have used the inbuilt markers from leaflet. But I have not seen any resource which can help me create and animate what I need to do.

This is the client side file I am dealing with :

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-12" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">
<div id='map' class = "map" style="border : 2px solid #182e69"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var watercolorLayer = new L.TileLayer("http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg", {noWrap : true});
var map = L.map('map',{scrollWheelZoom:true, maxZoom:5, minZoom:2}).setView([0,0], 2).addLayer(watercolorLayer);
map.setMaxBounds(map.getBounds()).fitWorld();
map._initPathRoot(); 
</script>

<script>
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("Connection established");

});

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]); //latitude obtained
    console.log(data[1]); //longitude obtained

});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update and post an answer to my question in case someone else needs it later on. I tried using CircleMarker objects from leaflet but it turns out I could not find any information about how to animate them.

So I finally figured it out using D3.

I created the SVG element on top of the map and then selected it like so :

```
map._initPathRoot(); 
var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg");
```

Then within the event handler for my websocket connection (receiving messages) I posted the following code :

```
 var Point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(data); //data is the websocket
                                           //event it receives and its a 
                                           //list with the 2 coordinates e.g "[lattitude, longtitude]"
    var circle = svg.append("circle")      //Adding circle element on coordinates
                .attr("cx", Point.x )
                .attr("cy", Point.y)
                .attr("r", 0)
                .style("fill", "#182e69")
                .attr("opacity", 0.5)
                .transition()              //adding first transition
                .attr("r", 50)
                .attr("opacity", 0.3)
                .delay(1000)
                .duration(1000)
                .on("end", function() {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .transition()             //adding second transition
                        .attr("r", 0)
                        .attr("opacity", 0.0)
                        .duration(500)
                        .on("end", function() {
                            d3.select(this).remove(); //removing the circle 
                                                     //element from the map
                                                     //after the transitions are done
                        });
                });
```